# How does BA work for 3d lidar? Particularly VLP16/VLP32 aren't dense enough

Tags: slam, lidar, ba

How do you run bundle adjustment on a sequence of 3d lidar recordings if the scan is relatively sparse? I read something about attempting to match up planes/edges but there wasn't much detail given. I think NDT and ICP can't work due to the sparseness of the scan.

Comment: Bundle adjustment is generally considered a computer vision technique. So you don't run it with LIDAR points.

So I guess you are trying to do some type of global optimization.

ICP and NDT you can run with very sparse scans. Even with VLP 16. The lidar slam package(https://github.com/rsasaki0109/lidarslam_ros2) even has an example with VLP 16.

Comment: There is no way NDT is going to work though, the points are just too sparse....

Comment: It looks like the papers do some form of feature extraction along planes and edges, but this only works in city areas...

Answer (score 0):

These lidar units can be sped up. That will give more detail in the output cloud. VLP16 can do from 300 to 1200 rpm, I believe.

Comment: No amount of speed changes the fact it has 16 scan lines, it's extremely sparse.